# where to point compile flags?

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, configure

i am trying to compile autogen on RHEL, and i'm running into some trouble.

fair warning, i don't know a whole lot about what i am doing here.

when i run ./configure from the command line, i eventually get the error messages:

```
configure: guile-config used for CFLAGS: -pthread -I/usr/local/include/guile/2.0 -I/usr/local/include  
configure: guile-config used for LIBS: -L/usr/local/lib -lguile-2.0 -lgc  
checking whether libguile can be linked with... no
configure: error: Cannot find libguile.  libguile is required.
```

but i have already compiled and installed libguile.  i have the .so/.a files for libguile in /usr/local/lib/, and /usr/local/include/guile/2.0/libguile has all of the header files and whatnot.  there is also a guile-2.0.pc in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.

i can try to run the configure script again, and use the --with-libguile, --with-libguile-cflags, and --with-libguile-libs options, but i don't know what to put where.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The configure script might not know about stuff in /usr/local/lib. Try doing:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

And then running configure. The LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is used to indicate to programs to look there for libraries.